# If the velocity of particle $A$ exceeds that of $B$, is the acceleration of $A$ greater than $B$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Two particles $A, B$ are travelling along parallel straight paths. At some point, the velocity of $A$ exceeds that of $B$. Does this *necessarily* mean that the acceleration of $A$ is greater than the acceleration of $B$?

If you look at the $v - t$ graph of the two particles, the lines would intersect. Probably, starting off, the velocity of $B$  would be greater, but since the slope of the velocity of $A$ would be greater it would intersect with the graph of $B$ and exceed it. I couldn't think of any other situation. So, my conclusion was that the acceleration has to be greater. But my textbook says otherwise. How come?

EDIT: This is question 13 from chapter 2 in Resnick halliday physics.

To clarify: the problem does NOT assume that initally A's velocity was lower than B's. (See comments)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. If A starts with a high velocity and travels at constant speed and B starts from rest and is accelerated, than obviously A's velocity is greater than that of B and B's acceleration (>0) exceeds that of A (=0).

Comment: No. The question says that *at some point$ A's velocity exceeds B's. It wasn't higher to begin with.

Comment: You should make that clear. The origin is also *some point*.

Comment: Are you talking about average or momentary accelerations?

Comment: Acceleration of both particles is assumed to be constant. If you are unclear about the question: This is question 13 from Chapter 2 Resnick Halliday Physics.

Comment: @Gerard you should edit the question to mention that, then.  (Probably also add the [tag:homework] tag while you're at it)

Comment: OK. I don't have that textbook. If the v-t line of A crosses that of B *from below*, then necessarily at that point A's velocity has to be greater than that of B. Since it's assumed to be constant that's your answer. If your textbook says otherwise, carefully check whether the formulation of the problem leaves a loop-hole for the crossing to be from above.

Comment: The exact wording of the question is "Two cars are moving in the same direction in parallel lanes along a highway. At some instant the velocity of car A exceeds the velocity of car B. Does this mean that the acceleration of car A is greater than that of car B?"

Comment: So the problem does not assume that initally A's velocity was lower than B's. So my first comment applies and the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  It does not necessarily mean that the acceleration of $A$ is greater than the acceleration of $B$.  Here's an explicit counterexample:

Object $A$ is moving at $10\,\mathrm{m/s}$ with constant velocity while object $B$ is moving at $5\,\mathrm{m/s}$ with an acceleration of $1\, \mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$.  In this case, the acceleration of $A$ is zero, so $B$'s acceleration is greater, but it's velocity is lower.

Note that the initial conditions of the motions of the two objects are irrelevant; we're talking about instantaneous velocities and accelerations, and given any two objects, one can completely independently pick their velocities and accelerations.